# Javascript "..." waiting dot looping with interval

Tags: javascript, loops, intervals

Instead of using an animated gif, I would like to instead have text in a span:

1. Waiting
2. Waiting.
3. Waiting..
4. Waiting...

I would like to loop through each and then return to the first in an infinite loop.  I would also like to control the interval to speed up or slow it down.  I'd like to have my HTML to be:

```
<p>Waiting<span id="dots"></span></p>
```

And simply cycle the span innerHTML.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a "Get a free slave" website.

Comment: ItzWarty, I'm fairly new here on stackoverflow but you'll find that I make contributions all over the web with work I'm doing.  I contribute to the WordPress community a lot (lots of free plugins at my site).  As well, when the opportunity arises, I've paid for the work or donated to people's PayPals.

Before you go to the extent of insulting someone, you should do a little research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably set you in the right direction. I think the code should explain itself.

```
function iterateDots(){
    var el = document.getElementById("dots");
    var dotsStr = el.innerHTML;
    var dotsLen = dotsStr.length;

    var maxDots = 3;
    el.innerHTML = (dotsLen < maxDots ? dotsStr + '.' : '');
}

function startLoading(){
    var intervalMs = 300;

    var interval = setInterval("iterateDots()", intervalMs);
}
```

Comment: That nailed it!  Thanks Julian!

Answer (score 0):

`dots = document.getElementById('dots');` will get the DOM element you want to put dots in, and the `innerHTML` attribute of that element will let you manipulate the content inside it.

As for changing the content of the span on a specific interval, have a look at [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). You'll have to pick the one that best suits your needs.

I'm not going to post an actual solution since you haven't really showed any effort on this one, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Carson! You'll see more effort as I continue to dive into the community - I promise.